# How to display xml content with html tags and view it as html using Jquery load

Tags: jquery, html, browser

I want to display xml content with html tags and view it in an html format via browser using jquery load.

Issue: The html tags are displayed with actual html tags (i.e. `<p> or <br>`) in the browser and need to convert it to html format.

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<catalog>
    <title>Catalog 1</title>
    <text_area><p>This is my Test Catalog1</p><br>This is the second line<br>Last line. <b>End</b></text_area> 
</catalog>
```

I have this html, js code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script></head>
<body>

<b>Catalog</b><br>
Title:<div id="title"></div><br>
Content:<div id="text_area"></div><br>


<script>
var getvar = "catalog.xml";
$( "#title" ).load("catalog.xml title");
$( "#text_area" ).load("catalog.xml text_area");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

With my code, the result shows:

**Catalog**

```
Title: Catalog 1
Content:<p>This is my Test Catalog1</p><br>This is the second line<br>Last line. <b>End</b>
```

Need to convert this and get this expected results:

**Catalog**

Title: Catalog 1

Content: 
This is my Test Catalog1

This is the second line

Last line.

**End**

Comment: Not certain interpret Question correctly ? `xml` not loading as expected ?

Comment: xml is loading with actual html tags in browser. Need to display it as html format content (for the text_area node). I've provided my details, let me know what code or details that are confusing?